# iPad 2 not respecting media query for email

Tags: html, css, ipad, email, media-queries

So I recently encountered a problem having to do with mail for the iPad 2.

I have this media query:

```
@media only screen and
  (max-width: 727px) {
     ...
  }
```

(I'm using 727 simply to start scaling down things once the screen width is less then the masthead of the email.

The issue is, that for the iPad 2 (and I'm also assuming 1, but I dont have one to test with), that it doesnt start respecting that media query unless I go all the way down to 701px for the max-width.

It seems to work on iPad3 (at least according to litmus, because I also dont have a physical device to test with).

Has anyone else encountered this? I was under the assumption that the iPad had a max-width of 768px.

Edit: Sorry I wasn't clear about this initially but for iPad2 it is actually using this media query (which I do not expect, since the device width is suppoed to be 768px), but for iPad3 it is not actually interpreting it.

Comment: what are your meta headers? specifically, your viewport meta. it might be worth checking this: http://www.allenpike.com/2010/choosing-a-viewport-for-ipad-sites/ out

Comment: I've tried it both with no meta tag and with "width=device-width" and no dice for either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my email template on the iPad Mini. This was my original @media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  ...
}
```

But as you noted (thanks by the way!) the iPad was picking these up. I've only tested on the iPad mini, but I was able to “trick” the iPad into ignoring them by adding a `max-device-width` declaration like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) and (max-device-width: 760px) {
  ...
}
```

*Note: What compounded the problem was that Litmus showed the iPad Mini as ignoring the mobile-only CSS, but when I tested it on the actual device it was picking them up.*